# How to clip part of a sprite based on its position?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm designing a game in Cocos2d, and at one point I have coins shooting out on a platform from a zelda-ish perspective. I'd like to display the coin's shadow sprite (a different sprite from the coin) on the platform, but mask or clip the shadow sprite on the edge of the platform. The coin can continue off the edge of the platform, but the shadow should stop at the edge. The platform also moves, so I need the shadow sprite to track with the platform's movement.

I thought it could work to use a CCClippingNode for this, but I can't add it as a child of anything in a spriteBatchNode which is how I'm making my platform. Without having the shadow as a child of the platform, I'll mess up z-order and the shadow movement won't track correctly. I also checked out Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on masking a sprite but I don't think that'll work since it looks like it masks an individual sprite texture and not an area of the view where the sprite shouldn't be displayed. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I would use a shader for this : pass a float which represents the % of width to be displayed, and if the fragment is right of the threshold, change transparency to 100% (i am assuming the shadow stands right of the center point of the coin).

Comment: I think you need to make the clipping node the width of the platform, add it to the scene that the platform is in, with its lowest y point at the top of the platform, and then move the clipping node at the same time as the platform (either by being a child, or it's own actions). Then add the coin shadows to the clipping node. You than have to add a "negate movement" action to the coin shadows that does the opposite of the movement of the clipping node, so that the coin shadows still appear to follow the movement of the coins.

Comment: You might be able to animate the mask node inside of the clippingNode, which would save you some extra work not having to negate the movement on the coins, but I haven't touched cocos in quite a while, so take all with a grain of salt.

Comment: I don't think it'll work to have the shadows as a child of the clipping node because the clipping node will need to be on a higher z-order than the platform. If the other elements are children of the platform, they'll display under the shadows. I could instead make nothing the child of the platform, and add a whole extra bunch to mess with the math of making the movement right. That seems to be what I'll need to do to get this to work if I use clipping node. I'm not sure how to write the shader, would that be with OpenGL?